# Minced oaths in Spanish

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vulgaridades, interjecciones, eufemismos

In English there are a variety of [minced oaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath), e.g. *oh my gosh* ("oh my God"), *darn* ("damn"), *heck* ("hell") etc. Similarly in Catalan one often hears [*ostres*](https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/ostres) (esp. *ostras*) in place of "hòstia".

Are there any examples of this in Spanish? The only one that comes to mind is the very Alatriste-ish [*pardiez*](http://spanishskulduggery.tumblr.com/post/175642903967/more-of-an-english-ask-but-ive-noticed-that-in) for "por Diós".

Comment: I'd say this is too broad. I can think of several examples some of them very regional.   I would imaging that each region has several so I think this could produce a list of hundreds of expressions. i.e Hijuemichica,Hijuepucha, Sacar el cu..erpo, hacerse el Manuel, hablar paja, la ca..., are a few that we use in Colombia.

Comment: La definición de eufemismo es: 
**1. m. Manifestación suave o decorosa de ideas cuya recta y franca expresión sería dura o malsonante.** por lo que la respuesta a esta pregunta seria **todos los eufemismos del español**

Comment: @DGaleano eso pensé yo al principio, pero hay una diferencia entre decir "métetelo por _donde amargan los pepinos_" o "por _donde la espalda pierde su casto nombre_" para no decir "culo" (que sería también un eufemismo) y el decir "me cago en _dos_" para no decir "Dios". Entiendo que ese "minced oaths" no es realmente "eufemismo" si no "interjecciones suavizadas que intentan preservar un parecido fonético al original".

Comment: En México: "Asu" (para su madre).

Comment: I wonder if [ojalá](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ojal%C3%A1) would count. It's not used as an oath,  per se, but it has a similar etymology.

Comment: @Flimzy - I guess it wouldn't count for this question.  But maybe you could construct a different questions where that would fit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sí, ocurre en español.

Tienes por ejemplo:

- Gilipichis, gilitonto y similares por "gilipollas", que sería uno de los ejemplos más claros.
- [Jolín](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MVzRpRb%7CMW6Wl04)/Jolines por "joder". Se ve también con interjecciones como "¡Jopé!"

Incluso [gibar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JArwtYC), en su segunda acepción (Fastidiar, molestar, vejar.) podría entenderse por su sonoridad como una versión suavizada de "joder" ("hay que gibarse" vs. "hay que joderse").

- La interjección "¡Mecachis…!" deriva del "me cago en ..."
- La expresión "ajo y agua" es una suerte de eufemismo para "ajo(derse) y agua(ntarse)".
- "Córcholis" o incluso "concho" (también "recórcholis") es la versión suavizada de "coño" usado como interjección.
- La interjección "[diantre(s)](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DfOK59R)" es, como indica la RAE, un eufemismo coloquial para el más grosero "diablos"
- La RAE también incluye "[caray](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7RRDeQU%7C7RRgw5M)" como un eufemismo coloquial. Entiendo que este viene de "[carajo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7PHLd6o)", aunque esta palabra en principio no es tan malsonate como otras de las incluidas en esta respuesta.

Comment: Diantres y caray me hacen acordar de mis tías que no se atreven a usar groserías. :-)

Comment: Añado  que estaba pensando incluir "dichoso" en al lista, ya que a veces para no decir cosas como "Donde está el _maldito_ mando a distancia" (o similar) decimos "Dónde está el _dichoso_ mando a distancia?", pero entiendo que "dichoso" no guarda la similitud en sonoridad con otros términos que reemplaza y no es por tanto un caso de"minced oaths".

Comment: Jolí(n) viene de verdad de joder? Pensaba que era algún anglicismo convertido en interjección de *Holy!*

Comment: @guifa No sé si viene de joder o no. Ignoro la etimología, pero en cualquier caso, la similitud sonora, y que es una interjección "suave", hace que pueda ser usado como "minced oath".

Comment: @diego eso sin duda.

Comment: Yo añadiría *ostras* por *hostias*.

Comment: Parece que *gilipollas* viene de [*gilipichi*](http://revistas.rae.es/bilrae/article/view/285/716), y no al revés. También parece que *jolín* tiene origen árabe, y no viene de *joder*.

Answer (score 6):

Otros ejemplos:

- "Cajones" en lugar de "cojones".
- "¡Miércoles!" en lugar de "¡Mierda!"
- Además del comentado por @ukemi  *"¡Mecachis (en la mar)!"*, existe el algo más explícito *¡Mecagüen!*.
- "Repámpanos" lo he visto en tebeos, pero no se usa hoy día.
- "Jorobar" también puede ser un sustituto de joder: "*No me jorobes*".

Comment: Interesante que "jorobar" y "gibar" son sinónimos. Es como hacer que a alguien le salga [chepa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8gyX2f9), o joroba (o corcova).

Answer (score 2):

One that I didn't realise was a minced oath: [*caramba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A1Ay,_caramba!) in place of *carajo*.

[image: Bart Simpson: "Ay caramba!"]