# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "gilipollas"?

Tags: etimología, insultos

En Twitter existe una interesantísima cuenta llamada Etimologías (@EtimosDirectos) que hoy habla sobre la palabra **gilipollas**, un insulto típico de España:

> Aunque la etimología presentada aquí no deja de ser una leyenda urbana muy difundida (GILIPOLLAS se documenta por primera vez en el siglo XX, del caló "jili", necio, y "polla"), si que hay una anécdota histórica que pudo haber dado pábulo al rumor: las GILIMONAS.
>
> <sub>[Etimologías en Twitter, 6 septiembre 2019](https://twitter.com/EtimosDirectos/status/1169954951205916673)</sub>

La etimología que referencia es otra dada en:

> La palabra Gilipollas nació con el Ministro de Hacienda de Felipe III Baltasar GIL Imón. Tenía 3 hijas poco agraciadas que iban con él a todos lados, se les llamaba POLLAS, por estar en edad casadera. Entonces decían viene GIL y sus POLLAS, terminando en Gilipollas.
>
> <sub>[RelatandoHistoria en Twitter, 6 septiembre 2019](https://twitter.com/relatandohisto1/status/1169942925721186305)</sub>

En respuestas a este último tuit, los dos usuarios se enfrascan en un interesante debate sobre cuál es el verdadero origen de la palabra, cada uno con sus argumentos (uno de Corominas, otro de un artículo del ABC).

Luego veo que [ukemi en una ocasión comentó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29047/minced-oaths-in-spanish/29048#comment50233_29048):

> Parece que *gilipollas* viene de [*gilipichi*](http://revistas.rae.es/bilrae/article/view/285/716), y no al revés. También parece que *jolín* tiene origen árabe, y no viene de *joder*.

La duda que me surge es: ¿existe alguna fuente fiable que indique el origen de esta palabra?

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que pude ver

> "***gilipollas***" tiene origen en la palabra ***jili*** (o ***gilí***)  del [caló](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_cal%C3%B3) (el caló es una variedad del romaní, que es una de las lenguas más antiguas del mundo, hablada en  la comunidad gitana en Europa y Asia)

Cito [de este artículo](https://www.elperiodico.com/es/politica/20170110/donde-viene-palabra-gilipollas-5735565)  (donde la destacación en negritas es mía)

> El filólogo **Joan Coromines** **en su 'Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico' coincide con la RAE y expertos como el alemán Max-Leopold Wagner o el catalán Juan Givanel** **en atribuir su origen una palabra caló:** ***"Gilí, 'tonto, memo', del gitano español*** ***jili***, ***'inocente, cándido', derivado de jil 'fresco', jilar 'enfriar'"***. De ahí derivarían términos como gilipollas, y eufemismos para evitar la palabra malsonante como 'gilipuertas'. ***Polla*, que procede del latín '*pullus*' -cría de cualquier animal-, es una extendida metáfora del pene**. La combinación de ambos términos es similar a la que se produce en otras expresiones groseras para definir a alguien como corto de entendederas, como 'tonto del culo', o que no piensa precisamente con su cerebro sino con otro órgano. La construcción también tiene paralelismos en el catalán, como 'capdefava' o  'titafreda', en este último caso con el significado de pusilánime.

La obra de **Joan Coromines** es el "Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico" (que no tiene versiones electrónicas) pero puede consultarse en varias bibliotecas públicas del mundo [cuyas ubicaciones pueden consultarse aquí](https://www.worldcat.org/title/breve-diccionario-etimologico-de-la-lengua-castellana/oclc/1059182/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true)

Por otro lado existe esta otra referencia coincidente con el origen gitano del término, dentro de un libro del estudioso José Gobello [Blanqueo etimológico del Lunfardo](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=bVH7Qiw4qpkC&pg=PA35&dq=cal%C3%B3%20gil%C3%AC&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijlPDewuLkAhU1H7kGHdG7ARcQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)) 
[image: Gil, palabra caló por bobo y tonto]

La referencia al especialista alemán Wagner, quien finca en la lengua caló la etimología, aparece confirmada en este [estudio lexicográfico "El Arte del Insulto"](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=IURdAAAAMAAJ&q=cal%C3%B3%20gili%20gilipollas&dq=cal%C3%B3%20gili%20gilipollas&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYqOH7z-LkAhXIIrkGHbxtDhEQ6AEIYTAJ)

[image: captura con los término encontrados en Google books]
https://www.worldcat.org/title/breve-diccionario-etimologico-de-la-lengua-castellana/oclc/854742587?referer=di&ht=edition

Comment: En Argentina un "gil" es uno que se puede engañar o estafar fácilmente.

Comment: Claro, en Argentina  usamos exactamente la derivación de esa palabra gitana ("jili"),  ***gil*** como sinónimo de ingenuo o tonto
"Fulano se está haciendo el gil"  (simulando ser medio estúpido)